# How to enable cgroups in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

In Linux I think there is a mechanism to kill the application.

I want to know what is in the condition that will cause an application to be killed?

For example, I think that there are insufficient memory, a certain number of application launches, and so on.

Control group (cgroups) which supported by Linux kernel permitting to limit resource used for an application.
(memory, bandwidth, disk, …). Once a particular app exceeds the permitted resource, it will be automatically killed.

How to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following modification to do_configure_append() in linux-kernel.bb.

```
# cgroups
kernel_configure_variable CGROUPS y
kernel_configure_variable CGROUP_FREEZER y
kernel_configure_variable CGROUP_PIDS y
kernel_configure_variable CGROUP_DEVICE y
kernel_configure_variable CPUSETS y
kernel_configure_variable PROC_PID_CPUSET y
kernel_configure_variable CGROUP_CPUACCT y
kernel_configure_variable PAGE_COUNTER y
kernel_configure_variable MEMCG y
kernel_configure_variable CGROUP_SCHED y

kernel_configure_variable NAMESPACES y

# overlay fs
kernel_configure_variable OVERLAY_FS y
```

[image]

References:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide